# Scraping a class element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape `class="cms-no-route cms-noroute-index page-layout-1column"` in `<body data-containr="body" class="cms-no-route cms-noroute-index page-layout-1column">` and save it in a txt file, but for some reason when I run the script nothing happens.

```
def get():
 source = requests.get("https://shop.adidas.ae/en/yeezy-boost-350-v2-ash-pearl/GY7658.html", headers=randomheaders.LoadHeader()).text
 soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
 x = soup.find_all('body', datacontainer_="body")
 url = x.get('class')
 filename = "adidaslive.txt"
 with open(filename, "r") as rf:
   with open(filename, "a") as af:
     if url not in rf:
       print(url)
       af.write("\n" + url)
     else:
      print("nothing")
```

Comment: Edited as per the 1st answer but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
def get():
    source = ...
```

You need to properly indent your code

```py
x = soup.find_all('body', datacontainer_="body")
```

`x` here is a list with only one element because, there is only one 'body' tag in your html source code.